# Inheritance and Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, inheritance

I am trying to create a file writer based on Pandas' `ExcelWriter`. I proceeded as I usually do with classes in Python (3) with inheritance:

```
import pandas as pd

class Writer(pd.ExcelWriter):
    def __init__(self, fname, engine='openpyxl'):
        pd.ExcelWriter.__init__(self, fname, engine=engine)
        self.newvar = 0
```

However, when I try to use it, I cannot access `newvar`:

```
test = Writer('test.xlsx')
test.newvar
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: '_XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'nmax'
```

And when I check the type of `test`, it returns:

```
pandas.io.excel._XlsxWriter
```

I don't understand what I am missing since I used this kind of inheritance in many other cases. Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`pandas.ExcelWriter.__new__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L701) returns a different class than itself (actually it is an [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta)). The class is chosen based on the extension of the file path and the engine which is used - you could observe that when you checked the type of the newly created instance. That means the `__init__` method of whatever class is returned gets called. You can think of `ExcelWriter` as some kind of proxy for the specific writers for each format and engine (though it also defines the API which such a writer must provide).

In order to make your writer available (for the given engine), you need to [register](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L156) it.

But before you can do that you need to make your class compatible by following the instructions which you'll find via [`help(pandas.ExcelWriter)`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L680). For the sake of completeness I cite them here:

```
# Defining an ExcelWriter implementation (see abstract methods for more...)

# - Mandatory
#   - ``write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name=None, startrow=0, startcol=0)``
#     --> called to write additional DataFrames to disk
#   - ``supported_extensions`` (tuple of supported extensions), used to
#      check that engine supports the given extension.
#   - ``engine`` - string that gives the engine name. Necessary to
#     instantiate class directly and bypass ``ExcelWriterMeta`` engine
#     lookup.
#   - ``save(self)`` --> called to save file to disk
# - Mostly mandatory (i.e. should at least exist)
#   - book, cur_sheet, path

# - Optional:
#   - ``__init__(self, path, engine=None, **kwargs)`` --> always called
#     with path as first argument.
```

So with that in mind we can extend your class:

```
class Writer(pd.ExcelWriter):
    engine = 'openpyxl'
    supported_extensions = ('xlsx',)

    def write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name=None, startrow=0, startcol=0):
        # Implement something useful here.
        pass

    def save(self):
        # Implement something useful here.
        pass

    def __init__(self, fname, engine='openpyxl', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, fname, engine=engine, **kwargs)
```

Now you can use `pd.io.excel.register_writer(Writer)` to register the writer. But you need to make sure the engine which you've specified matches your version of `openpyxl`. You can check the process of how a specific writer is chosen [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L183); the writers which are currently registered for each version can be checked via `print(pd.io.excel._writers)`.

As a side note: You can also subclass one of the already available specific writers and reuse their `write_cells` and `save` methods for example (however you'll need to register your writer also in that case):

- [`_Openpyxl1Writer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L826)
- [`_Openpyxl20Writer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L957)
- [`_Openpyxl22Writer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L1369)
- [`_XlwtWriter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L1444)
- [`_XlsxWriter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ff1241fa794231b8317ebe96b66f71dce99e0c2/pandas/io/excel.py#L1576)

Comment: Spot-on! It's a very neat answer! +1